# Eclipse don't find installed JRE on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, java

I'm trying to work with JAVA in Eclpise (Helios) and I'm running on Mac OS X 10.6.7. When I try to open a new Java Project it tells me that I don't have any JRE installed.

Using terminal it says that the current javac -version is 1.6.0_22. Now, I read about specifying a path in Eclipse->Preferences->Java->installed JRE to Library/Framework/JavaVM/Versions/1.6/home the problem is that after "Versions" I'm finding only "aliases" and not folders. If I click on that, it tells me that the alias is not working.

So I'm stuck here: anybody has a solution?

---

I found a solution so I would like to share. Actually nothing worked, I ve also called Apple and they had no idea. So I ve downloaded Windows 7 and installed it on my Mac with bootcamp. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this post [solution!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736993/eclipse-mac-os-default-jre-missing)

It helped me solve my problem I had on my mac after a fresh install of leopard. Seems like these variables have to be set manually or so.

Answer (score 2):

Click on project--> Build Path-->Configure Build Path...-->Libraries tab-->Click on Add Library button. Select JRE System library than select JRE if not found than you can specify your own JRE.I think this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Make your eclipse Pointing `INSTALLED JRE` to `JDK`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it doesn't work on a mac (got no way to check), but since it's a Unix system:

in the terminal, execute `which javac`

Strip `/bin/javac` from the output and you have the path that eclipse needs

Comment: @Jordan ok, but /usr/bin/javac is probably just a symbolic link. So you need to do `realpath /usr/bean/javac` and do the above with the output. See [this page about `realpath`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-find-real-physical-path/)

Comment: Huh. Looks like OS X doesn't even have the `realpath` command (although there's a man page for it, oddly). Using `ls -l` shows that it points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac`
so I suppose it'd be `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/` But I think that's not the correct path for OS X anyway; tried it in Eclipse and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jordan no, I'm pretty sure /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javac is another symbolic link. try ls -l on that, too

Answer (score 0):

What is the PATH to the JRE file?
Not something else, but the ~JRE~ (Java Runtime Environment)
As needed for http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/wiki/RayMediaServerInstallation

Answer (score 0):

On my macbook pro I had the same problem: in an imported Java project, some libraries cannot found (like java.time).

I've tried some tutorials but at the end I solved **installing the last JRE** version and **removing all old versions** from `System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`

Hoping to be useful

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to get the Eclipse-Oxygen. After watching a bunch of youtube videos and trying above hints nothing worked, I kept getting

> 'Launching HTTP Preview at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>   Could not find JRE executable.

Then I saw [this post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1068790/) where Nitin Dahyabhai writes it is a Mac-specific bug that is fixed for Eclipse-Oxygen

I uploaded Eclipse-Oxygen (Eclipse IDE for Javascript and Web Developers) using eclipseinstaller by Oomph--- and LO and BEHOLD preview of my html page was immediate, no set up required!