# How do I add the Java 7 JRE to Eclipse on my mac?

Tags: eclipse, java

I have a mac and I recently installed Java 7 on it.  However, my question is, how do I let Eclipse (Juno) know about this installation.  I went to the preferences menu and selected Java > Installed JREs to get to this screen

[image]

I've clicking the add button but I'm not sure what I need to add:

[image]

I would have thought that I should add the .jdk file but it eclipse doesn't like that.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736993/eclipse-mac-os-default-jre-missing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the latest version (07) you can type in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/
instead of using the directory... button

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it through the Eclipse dialog as well once I saw the path.