# Cannot create a new Android Project in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

I see there are some familiar questions, i tried most of the solutions. unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

I get the error log from  workspace/.metadata/.log file. the log is as below:

```
!SESSION 2014-07-08 03:22:15.704 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/wuchangxi/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/wuchangxi/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2014-07-08 03:22:24.119
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2014-07-08 03:22:59.463
!MESSAGE
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard.performFinish(TemplateWizard.java:197)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.performFinish(NewProjectWizard.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3658)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger.process(ManifestMerger.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.mergeManifest(TemplateHandler.java:924)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.merge(TemplateHandler.java:760)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.access$7(TemplateHandler.java:705)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler$2.startElement(TemplateHandler.java:629)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.execute(TemplateHandler.java:595)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.access$1(TemplateHandler.java:578)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler$1.startElement(TemplateHandler.java:503)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.processVariables(TemplateHandler.java:471)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.render(TemplateHandler.java:319)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.generateActivity(NewProjectWizard.java:418)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.access$5(NewProjectWizard.java:401)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard$2.populate(NewProjectWizard.java:354)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createEclipseProject(NewProjectCreator.java:759)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.access$1(NewProjectCreator.java:712)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator$5.run(NewProjectCreator.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.create(NewProjectCreator.java:933)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.performFinish(NewProjectWizard.java:359)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard$1.run(TemplateWizard.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder._newFactory(XPathFactoryFinder.java:220)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder.newFactory(XPathFactoryFinder.java:141)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:182)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:96)
    at com.android.xml.AndroidXPathFactory.<clinit>(AndroidXPathFactory.java:37)
    ... 48 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger.process(ManifestMerger.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.mergeManifest(TemplateHandler.java:924)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.merge(TemplateHandler.java:760)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.access$7(TemplateHandler.java:705)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler$2.startElement(TemplateHandler.java:629)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.execute(TemplateHandler.java:595)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.access$1(TemplateHandler.java:578)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler$1.startElement(TemplateHandler.java:503)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1342)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.processVariables(TemplateHandler.java:471)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateHandler.render(TemplateHandler.java:319)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.generateActivity(NewProjectWizard.java:418)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.access$5(NewProjectWizard.java:401)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard$2.populate(NewProjectWizard.java:354)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.createEclipseProject(NewProjectCreator.java:759)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.access$1(NewProjectCreator.java:712)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator$5.run(NewProjectCreator.java:914)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.NewProjectCreator.create(NewProjectCreator.java:933)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.NewProjectWizard.performFinish(NewProjectWizard.java:359)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.templates.TemplateWizard$1.run(TemplateWizard.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder._newFactory(XPathFactoryFinder.java:220)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryFinder.newFactory(XPathFactoryFinder.java:141)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:182)
    at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:96)
    at com.android.xml.AndroidXPathFactory.<clinit>(AndroidXPathFactory.java:37)
    ... 48 more
```

what i tried:
1) download & install a new eclipse from eclipse website, doesn't work
2) uninstall all the unnecessary plugins,(eclipse colour theme, moonrise, the ADT is still there)
3) New Android Project in Android Studio with the same SDK, it works. as i notice, the JRE in Android Studio using is JDK 1.6 instead of 1.7 as i set in JAVA_HOME. I try to set the JRE of eclipse to 1.6 in the Preference as [this suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736993/eclipse-mac-os-default-jre-missing) but it's still in jdk 1.7

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this by setting eclipse's JRE to 1.6.0.

The detail is add following commands to the eclipse.ini file.

```
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Commands/java
```

eclipse.ini is in the `eclipse.app-->Contents-->MacOS-->eclipse.ini`

Hope this will help others.