# The magic behind "org.eclipse.equinox.ds@3:start"?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have a standalone headless RCP with the following command line arguments.

```
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -clean -consoleLog
```

I could successfully generate the binary to be run as a command line tool, but the issue is that I have to modify the config.ini file from

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,
org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,
org.eclipse.equinox.ds@2:start,
org.eclipse.core.runtime@s
```

to

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,
org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,
org.eclipse.equinox.ds@3:start, <---
org.eclipse.core.runtime@s
```

Without this change, I got these error messages when I execute the binary.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.0.v20120522-1841 [3]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.event; version="1.0.0"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
```

The magic behind "org.eclipse.equinox.ds@3:start"? Why it works well after my change? How can I setup in eclipse IDE so that I don't have to manually change the ini file all the time when I create the headless RCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can explain the magic behind the change, but I unfortunately am not familiar with exporting applications from Eclipse.

[`osgi.bundles`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html#osgibundles) is a property that defines what bundles are available and when (e.g. at what [start level](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/service/startlevel/StartLevel.html)) they should they start. The platform loads and starts those bundles at level 1, then 2, and so on up until `osgi.startLevel` (by default is 6, described in the juno doc linked above).

In order to start `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` the platform needs to load a bundle that exports version 1.0.0 of the `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.event` package.  From some searching this seems to be the [`org.eclipse.equinox.util`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.bundles.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.util/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) bundle.

So by changing from @2 to @3 you're pushing the starting of the ds bundle to be later in the startup of the platform to a point after the util bundle is loaded. I suspect what is helping here is the `org.eclipse.update.configurator` bundle (as it's a bundle whose job is to [load all the bundles from the plugins directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801463/504685).)